# how to validate a column, row or cell in apache poi is in a group and whether or not it is collapsed

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to validate through a unit test that a group has been defined and the current collapse state. If I cannot check for columns via the sheet, it would be okay to test the state of each cell. I do not see any methods like isGroup() isGroupCollapsed().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group is present if rows or columns have outline levels greater than 0. And a group is collapsed if all group members (rows or columns) are hidden.

For rows it is possible determining the outline level and hidden status of the rows. The current `apache poi 4.1.2` provides that by methods [Row.getOutlineLevel](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getOutlineLevel--) and [Row.getZeroHeight](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getZeroHeight--). If a row has a outline level greater than 0, then it belongs to a group having that outline level. The group starts at the smallest previous row having an outline level which is not lower than the outline level of that row. The group ends at the biggest subsequent row having an outline level which is not lower than the outline level of that row. And if all consecutive rows between group's start row and group's end row are hidden, then the whole group is hidden and is collapsed.

So we could loop over all rows in the sheet and have methods which can collect row-group-information from a row. In following code this are methods

```
int findStartOfRowOutlineGroup(Row row)
```

and

```
int findEndOfRowOutlineGroup(Row row)
```

and

```
boolean getIsWholeRowGroupHidden(Sheet sheet, int startOfRowOutlineGroup, int endOfRowOutlineGroup)
```

For columns it is possible determining the outline level and hidden status of the columns from the sheet. The current `apache poi 4.1.2` provides that by methods [Sheet.getColumnOutlineLevel](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getColumnOutlineLevel-int-) and [Sheet.isColumnHidden](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#isColumnHidden-int-). If a column has an outline level greater than 0, then it belongs to a group having that outline level. The group starts at the smallest previous column having an outline level which is not lower than the outline level of that column. The group ends at the biggest subsequent column having an outline level which is not lower than the outline level of that column. And if all consecutive columns between group's start column and group's end column are hidden, then the whole group is hidden and is collapsed.

So we could loop over all columns in the sheet and have methods which can collect col-group-information from the sheet. In following code this are methods

```
int findStartOfColOutlineGroup(Sheet sheet, int col)
```

and

```
int findEndOfColOutlineGroup(Sheet sheet, int col)
```

and

```
boolean getIsWholeColGroupHidden(Sheet sheet, int startOfColOutlineGroup, int endOfColOutlineGroup)
```

Complete example:

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class ExcelColumnGroupsRowGroups {

 static String getRowGroupInfos(Row row) {
  int outlineLevel = row.getOutlineLevel();
  String result = "Row "+(row.getRowNum()+1)+" belongs to no group.";
  if (outlineLevel > 0) {
   int startOfRowOutlineGroup = findStartOfRowOutlineGroup(row); //0-based
   int endOfRowOutlineGroup = findEndOfRowOutlineGroup(row); //0-based
   boolean isRowHidden = row.getZeroHeight();
   boolean isWholeGroupHidden = getIsWholeRowGroupHidden(row.getSheet(), startOfRowOutlineGroup, endOfRowOutlineGroup);
   result =  "Row "+(row.getRowNum()+1)+" belongs to group having outline level:"+outlineLevel+". "
            +"Group starts at row "+(startOfRowOutlineGroup+1)+" and ends at row "+(endOfRowOutlineGroup+1)+". "
            +"Row "+(row.getRowNum()+1)+" is "+((isRowHidden)?"hidden":"not hidden")+". "
            +"Whole group is "+((isWholeGroupHidden)?"hidden":"not hidden")+". ";
  }
  return result;
 }

 static int findStartOfRowOutlineGroup(Row row) { //0-based
  int outlineLevel = row.getOutlineLevel();
  int r = row.getRowNum();
  if (outlineLevel > 0) {
   while (r >= 0) {
    row = row.getSheet().getRow(r);
    if (row == null) break;
    int prevOutlineLevel = row.getOutlineLevel();
    if (prevOutlineLevel < outlineLevel) break;
    r--;
   }
  }
  return r+1;
 }

 static int findEndOfRowOutlineGroup(Row row) { //0-based
  int outlineLevel = row.getOutlineLevel();
  int r = row.getRowNum();
  if (outlineLevel > 0) {
   while (r <= row.getSheet().getLastRowNum()) {
    row = row.getSheet().getRow(r);
    if (row == null) break;
    int prevOutlineLevel = row.getOutlineLevel();
    if (prevOutlineLevel < outlineLevel) break;
    r++;
   }
  }
  return r-1;
 }

 static boolean getIsWholeRowGroupHidden(Sheet sheet, int startOfRowOutlineGroup, int endOfRowOutlineGroup) {
  boolean result = true;
  Row row;
  for (int r = startOfRowOutlineGroup; r <= endOfRowOutlineGroup; r++) {
   row = sheet.getRow(r);
   if (row == null) {
    result = false;
    break;
   } else if (!row.getZeroHeight()) {
    result = false;
    break;
   }
  }
  return result;
 }

 static String getColGroupInfos(Sheet sheet, int c) {
  int outlineLevel = sheet.getColumnOutlineLevel(c);
  String result = "Col "+(c+1)+" belongs to no group.";
  if (outlineLevel > 0) {
   int startOfColOutlineGroup = findStartOfColOutlineGroup(sheet, c); //0-based
   int endOfColOutlineGroup = findEndOfColOutlineGroup(sheet, c); //0-based
   boolean isColHidden = sheet.isColumnHidden(c);
   boolean isWholeGroupHidden = getIsWholeColGroupHidden(sheet, startOfColOutlineGroup, endOfColOutlineGroup);
   result =  "Col "+(c+1)+" belongs to group having outline level:"+outlineLevel+". "
             +"Group starts at col "+(startOfColOutlineGroup+1)+" and ends at col "+(endOfColOutlineGroup+1)+". "
             +"Col "+(c+1)+" is "+((isColHidden)?"hidden":"not hidden")+". "
             +"Whole group is "+((isWholeGroupHidden)?"hidden":"not hidden")+". ";
  }
  return result;
 }

 static int findStartOfColOutlineGroup(Sheet sheet, int col) { //0-based
  int outlineLevel = sheet.getColumnOutlineLevel(col);
  int c = col;
  if (outlineLevel > 0) {
   while (c >= 0) {
    int prevOutlineLevel = sheet.getColumnOutlineLevel(c);
    if (prevOutlineLevel < outlineLevel) break;
    c--;
   }
  }
  return c+1;
 }

 static int findEndOfColOutlineGroup(Sheet sheet, int col) { //0-based
  int outlineLevel = sheet.getColumnOutlineLevel(col);
  int c = col;
  if (outlineLevel > 0) {
   while (c <= sheet.getWorkbook().getSpreadsheetVersion().getLastColumnIndex()) {
    int prevOutlineLevel = sheet.getColumnOutlineLevel(c);
    if (prevOutlineLevel < outlineLevel) break;
    c++;
   }
  }
  return c-1;
 }

 static boolean getIsWholeColGroupHidden(Sheet sheet, int startOfColOutlineGroup, int endOfColOutlineGroup) {
  boolean result = true;
  for (int c = startOfColOutlineGroup; c <= endOfColOutlineGroup; c++) {
   if (!sheet.isColumnHidden(c)) {
    result = false;
    break;
   }
  }
  return result;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelSheetGroupedColsAndRows.xlsx"));
  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelSheetGroupedColsAndRows.xls"));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  for (Row row : sheet) {
   String rowGroupInfos = getRowGroupInfos(row);
   System.out.println(rowGroupInfos);
  }

  for (int c = 0; c <= workbook.getSpreadsheetVersion().getLastColumnIndex(); c++) {
   if (sheet.getColumnOutlineLevel(c) > 0) {
    String colGroupInfos = getColGroupInfos(sheet, c);
    System.out.println(colGroupInfos);
   }
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: I happened upon the outline level trick and was exploring the relationship with the hidden value. You confirmed my thinking and gave a lot of good stuff. Being TDD, I find it often frustrating that POI allows setting values, but no obvious way to retrieve the state. Hopefully they will one day get there.

Comment: @Bill Turner: Well, I doubt it is possible to catch up decades of `Microsoft`'s `Excel` development having only public file description for `Office Open XML` (`*.xlsx`) and only that and reverse engineering results for binary file system `BIFF` (`*.xls`). At least if one not even follows the `Microsoft` `API`s but tries implementing own objects and methods. But maybe following the `Microsoft` `API`s or even the `Libreoffice` or `OpenOffice` `API`s would have legal problems. Considering that all, `apache poi` is on really good state.